DevOps Pipline Failure Nuget Restore Swagger-Net
We are working on an internal ASP.NET website (running on .NET 4.8) developed by people now gone from the company. Minor fixes have been done over time and builds have worked.
Now, however, we have a required fix and we're running into a problem where our build pipeline is failing with the message that it cannot find Swagger-Net 8.5.12.1. We suspect the issue might be that package signature validation failed because the certificate expired May 15, 2024. We are using the most recent version of Swagger-Net, and we have no control over what certificate they use.
Here are the details:
PackageSignatureVerificationLog: PackageIdentity: Swagger-Net.8.5.12.1 Source: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json PackageSignatureValidity: False

2024-07-22T19:19:12.2114233Z Installed:
2024-07-22T19:19:12.2114389Z     121 package(s) to packages.config projects
2024-07-22T19:19:12.2461572Z ##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Errors in packages.config projects
    Unable to find version '8.5.12.1' of package 'Swagger-Net'.
      C:\Users\s-BSD-TeamCity\.nuget\packages\: Package 'Swagger-Net.8.5.12.1' is not found on source 'C:\Users\s-BSD-TeamCity\.nuget\packages\'.
      https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ajgggbus/_packaging/ajgggbus_feed/nuget/v3/index.json: Package 'Swagger-Net.8.5.12.1' is not found on source 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ajgggbus/_packaging/ajgggbus_feed/nuget/v3/index.json'.
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json:)

Snippet from nuget.config.tfsbuild:
<trustedSigners>
    <author name="microsoft">
        <certificate fingerprint="3F9001EA83C560D712C24CF213C3D312CB3BFF51EE89435D3430BD06B5D0EECE" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="false" />
    </author>
    <repository name="nuget.org" serviceIndex="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json">
        <certificate fingerprint="0E5F38F57DC1BCC806D8494F4F90FBCEDD988B46760709CBEEC6F4219AA6157D" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="false" />
        <owners>microsoft;aspnet;nuget</owners>
    </repository>
</trustedSigners>

Please advise if there is any solution that doesn't require the author of the nuget package to renew the certificate.
I tried updating Swagger-Net from a previous version, to no avail. Otherwise, we've googled for alternative solutions and haven't found any.
